# Paste all combinations of a vector in R

Tags: r, paste

I have a vector say:

```
vec = c("A", "B", "C")
```

And I want to paste single combinations of every item in the vector
to get the result

```
AB
AC
BC
```

I know I can use outer to get all possible combinations  of the vector, but I am stumped as how to only get the result above. Order doesn't matter in this case, so the result could plausibly also be

```
BA
CA
CB
```

I just need to combine the single pairs.

Sam

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `combn`

```
 combn(vec,2, FUN=paste, collapse='')
 #[1] "AB" "AC" "BC"
```