# Paste all combinations of two separate vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, combinations, paste

I have two vectors

```
df1 <- c("a","b","c")
df2 <- c("1","2","3")

 # expected output
 #  a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
```

I've seen [Paste all combinations of a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549562/paste-all-combinations-of-a-vector-in-r), However, That doesn't solve my dilemma.

Comment: Try: `as.vector(t(outer(c("a","b","c"),c(1,2,3),'paste0')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

```
df1 <- c("a","b","c")
df2 <- c("1","2","3")

apply(expand.grid(df1, df2), 1, paste, collapse="")
```

Comment: or simply `do.call(paste0, expand.grid(df1, df2))`

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
paste0(rep(df1, length(df1)), rep(df2, length(df2)))
```

Or this:

```
df_comb <- expand.grid(df1, df2)
paste0(df_comb$Var1, df_comb$Var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `merge`: `apply(merge(df1, df2), 1, function(row) paste(row[1], row[2], sep = ''))`